# OS X Cocoa - Translate Virtual Scan Code to and from Char

Tags: cocoa, keyboard, macos-carbon, scancodes

Is there a cocoa / carbon equivalent to the VkKeyScan and ToUnicode functions present on windows for translating between virtual scan codes and a unicode string? I would also like to perform this conversion vice versa (going from a char to a scan code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is, sadly. [`CGEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGEventRef) and [`NSEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (which aren't toll-free bridged, but `NSEvent` can convert back and forth) are the standard containers for events including key presses and as a result can convert from device-dependent scan codes to unicode string sequences but there seems to be no way to go in the other direction — from a unicode character to the required sequence of device-dependent key presses.

There's a brief comment underneath [`CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent) that:

> All keystrokes needed to generate a character must be entered,
>   including modifier keys. For example, to produce a 'Z', the SHIFT key
>   must be down, the 'z' key must go down, and then the SHIFT and 'z' key
>   must be released:

But the sequence shown then has hardcoded and unexplained constants for the shift and z keys.

Answer (score 0):

`UCKeyTranslate()`.

Comment: Doesn't that only convert from a virtual key code to a unicode string?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this distinction is a Windows-specific piece of bad terminology, “virtual scan codes” being unvirtualized key codes. I don’t know where you’d _get_ “virtual scan codes” in this sense in Mac OS X. Possibly you’re dealing with HID usages, in which case the `kHID2VKC` table in my [KeyNaming](https://github.com/Ahruman/KeyNaming/blob/master/KeyNaming.c) library may be of interest.

Comment: Anyone coming here like I did, KeyNaming library is now [here](https://github.com/JensAyton/KeyNaming).